# How to add more than one google chart on a page from the same Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I have a snippet that works correctly with one google chart grabbing data from a google spreadsheet. However whenever I try to add another chart from a different range in the same spreadsheet, it overwrites to the original div.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Many thanks.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("visualization", "1.1", {
      packages: ["bar"]
    });
    //google.charts.load('upcoming', {'packages': ['geochart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawtotalChart);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawkpiChart);
    //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawKpiChart);
    //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);
    //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawOrdersChart);
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var totalChart;

    function drawtotalChart() {

      var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BvV9UHgppTBvZKtbvndZTM2qrvgE4Qeozfbzby5W5AQ/gviz/tq?range=G23:I32');


      // Send the query with a callback function.
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +
          response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

      var data = response.getDataTable();
      totalChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
      totalChart.draw(data, null);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawtotalChart);
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var kpiChart;

    function drawkpiChart() {

      var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BvV9UHgppTBvZKtbvndZTM2qrvgE4Qeozfbzby5W5AQ/gviz/tq?range=G36:K44');


      // Send the query with a callback function.
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +
          response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

      var kpi = response.getDataTable();
      kpiChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      kpiChart.draw(kpi, null);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawkpiChart);
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!--Table and divs that hold the charts-->
  <table class="columns">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="Geochart_div" style="width: 00px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reusing `handleQueryResponse` for both charts, and the one that loads first is being called to handle the queries for both charts.  Just because they're in different `<script>` blocks doesn't split them out of the same scope, so you're experiencing a conflict.  If you reorganize your JavaScript a bit, it should work:

```
// Load the bar chart package
google.charts.load("visualization", "1.1", {
    packages: ["bar"]
  });

// Set the chart callbacks
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawtotalChart);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawkpiChart);

var totalChart;

function drawtotalChart() {

  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BvV9UHgppTBvZKtbvndZTM2qrvgE4Qeozfbzby5W5AQ/gviz/tq?range=G23:I32');


  // Send the query with a callback function.
  query.send(handleTotalQueryResponse);
}

// Callback specific to the total chart
function handleTotalQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +
      response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  totalChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
  totalChart.draw(data, null);
}

var kpiChart;

function drawkpiChart() {

  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BvV9UHgppTBvZKtbvndZTM2qrvgE4Qeozfbzby5W5AQ/gviz/tq?range=G36:K44');


  // Send the query with a callback function.
  query.send(handleKpiQueryResponse);
}

// Callback specific to the KPI chart
function handleKpiQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +
      response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var kpi = response.getDataTable();
  kpiChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  kpiChart.draw(kpi, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize you must call them uniquely.

Comment: It's not so much that they _need_ to be called uniquely as much as only one of the duplicate methods (the one for the totals chart) was being used as the callback for both queries.  Naming them uniquely was one way to solve the problem

Comment: Also, if this helped you solve the problem, be sure to mark it as an answer so others facing a similar problem can find this question/answer more easily